# DataAnnotation [DataType(DataType.Date)] makes my field unnecessarily Required

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have the following field in my ViewModel:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Preferred date)")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
```

which produces the following markup:

```
<input class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Preferred date must be a date." data-val-required="The Preferred date field is required." id="EventDate" name="EventDate" type="date" value="">
```

If the user does not pick a value (i.e., leave this field empty - `value=""`) the returned data to the ViewModel is '{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}' and `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`.

I don't want this field to be required!

I tried to replace the markup with mine:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="EventDate" name="EventDate" type="date" value="1/1/1980">
```

However, the returned value is still '{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}' and `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`.

How can I disable the Required validation on this field (only)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing DateTime to DateTime? (making nullable) may solve it

Comment: @Murilo, sorry for my lack of understanding, can you elaborate please?

Comment: public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` does NOT make your property required - all that attribute does is tell the `@Html.EditorFor()` method to render `type="date"`. Its required because  typeof `DateTime` cannot have a `null` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Murilo I'll post the answer:

I changed my ViewModel field from:

```
public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
```

to

```
public Nullable<DateTime> EventDate { get; set; }
```